# How To Get Command Blocks Talking in Chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a way for a command block to say things in chat when it is powered, or more preferably whenever someone spawns into the world.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to try this yourself?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways you can output things to the chat.

The `/say` command, syntax `/say <Message ...>` displays a message in chat. However, this message will always have the command block's name beside it.

A command block with `/say Hello World!` would output:

```
[@] Hello World!
```

Alternatively, the `/tellraw` command, syntax `/tellraw <target> <json compound array/singleton>` displays a message in chat, but it gives you full customization of its output from color to formatting using `json` formatting.

A command block with `/tellraw @a {"text":"Hello World!"}` would output:

```
Hello World!
```

---

There are applications such as [minecraftjson.com](https://www.minecraftjson.com/) which generates a json string to use in `/tellraw` and various other commands that will give you complete control on what is outputted.

There is also a [Minepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text) section on the string format should you decide to write them yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `/say` command. This allows a command block to display a chat message to the entire server.

[More info on the /say command on the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#say)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to detect a Player do:

```
/testfor @e[type=Player]
```

In a repeating command block (always active). Then, have a chain command block (always active), connected to the first, saying:

```
/say <YOUR MESSAGE>
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax for 1st command: `/execute if entity @e[type=player]`. Also, why are you using `@e[type=player]` instead of just `@a`?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a pressure plate where you walk/spawn under the command block and have the command as `/say @a <Your message>`

Answer (score -1):

In newer versions, use:

```
/tellraw @e {"text":"MESSAGE"}
```

If you want your words to be in color, use:

```
/tellraw @e {"text":"MESSAGE","color":"COLOR"}
```

Comment: HI Minecraft Help, welcome to Stack Exchange! I unfortunately decided to downvote your answer, since you answer added nothing new that wasn't already told in the other answers. Aytimothy already mentioned in his answer that you could use `/tellraw`. But if you could elaborate on using the `/tellraw` command, your answer could definitely be valuable and add something! Since you are a new user, may I suggest checking out [the tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)?