# Is there a way to send a message to someone/everyone in the server from the console?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

In version 1.17, is there a way to send a message to someone/everyone in the server from the console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Get Command Blocks Talking in Chat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288709/how-to-get-command-blocks-talking-in-chat)

Comment: VTLO. The answers are the same, but the questions are different. [See meta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/391227).

Comment: @Schism Your "see meta" link is a circular link to this question.

Comment: Haha I copied from the wrong tab. Here's the link I meant to paste: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/

Comment: @Schism IMO they are too similar. We have closed many MC questions for a lot less similarity (which, I know, is not the best argumentation, but still).

Comment: @Joachim Upon reflection, I think if the proposed dupe target were edited to just ask about sending messages in chat with a command (which is not an unreasonable edit IMO), then I'd be happy to close it as a dupe. As it stands, I think they're _just_ dissimilar enough for me personally.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/288720/217855) to "How To Get Command Blocks Talking in Chat", linked originally by *pppery*:

> The /tellraw command, syntax /tellraw  <json compound array/singleton> displays a message in chat, but it gives you full customization of its output from color to formatting using json formatting.
>
> A command block with /tellraw @a {"text":"Hello World!"} would output:
>
> ```
> Hello World!
> ```

(Note that I have omitted some of the answer and kept the part of it I think you should go with - the `tellraw` command)

By the way, *aytimothy* also linked to [minecraftjson.com](https://www.minecraftjson.com/), which is a useful site for generating tellraw commands.

Comment: Copy-pasting answers from one question to another is counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

You can display it on their screen with `/title @a title <text>`